# hanging thread with thread.sleep(1000) needs almost 50 minutes

Tags: java, jvm

my customer cpu is over 100% with java processes. i search for this problem and i found an odd logging. A thread is going in sleep(1000) for 10 times, but it take almlost 50 minutes! 
what is going on???
maybe the problem with this sleeping thread comes from the high cpu-usage or the cpu is coming as a result of the sleeping thread.
i was looking with visualvm and i saw the sleeping thread. After then i make a test with the button "Perform GC" in visualvm. If i push this button, the logging of the thread was o.k. If may the settings of the java wrong?

```
java.lang.Runnable  

public void destroy() {
    LOG.debug("destroy " + getProgramName());

    Runnable destroyer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("RuntimeSystem-Destroyer");
            synchronized (lock) {
                runningSystemServiceDestroyers++;
            }

            try {

                unlockKopfsatzsperren();

                }
                remotingClosed();
            } catch (RemoteServiceException e) {
                LOG.error("Fehler", e);
            } finally {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    runningSystemServiceDestroyers--;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    destroyTask = executorService.submit(destroyer);
}

java.lang.Thread

private void unlockKopfsatzsperren() {

    long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 1; 

    int maxWait = 10;
    while (maxWait > 0) {
        try {
            LOG.info("wait for " + maxWait + " Sek.");
            maxWait--;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    ...
```

**and here are a snippet of the logging:**

- 06.01.2017 **13:02:39**.902 Info    wait for 6 Sek.
- 06.01.2017 **13:06:29**.333 Info    wait for 5 Sek.
- 06.01.2017 **13:15:26**.080 Info    wait for 4 Sek.
- 06.01.2017 **13:22:20**.519 Info    wait for 3 Sek.
- 06.01.2017 **13:27:44**.636 Info    wait for 2 Sek.
- 06.01.2017 **13:33:22**.530 Info    wait for 1 Sek.

*have a look at the timestamp!*

**and the JVM arguments**

- -Djava.awt.headless=true
- -Djava.awt.headless=true
- -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=191.2.2.1
- -Dgenero.service.ping.timeout=120
- -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345
- -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
- -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
- -Xms32m
- -Xmx512m
- -Djava.library.path=../lib
- -Dwrapper.key=oiirTtljthEYn2iF
- -Dwrapper.port=32007
- -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
- -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
- -Dwrapper.pid=27796
- -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
- -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
- -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
- -Dwrapper.disable_shutdown_hook=TRUE
- -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
- -Dwrapper.jvmid=1

the top:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuOhI.png)

Comment: Can you please post the correct code or the correct logging? Your code is unable to produce these log messages.

Comment: @Tom looks okay to me? "wait for 6 Sek." prefixed with a timestamp and the level (Info)

Comment: @Michael After his edit, but I wonder if there are other missing code parts in his snippet.

Comment: the implementation is java.lang.Thread

Comment: What happens if you do not wait at all here? Is the App still going to 100% CPU?

Comment: If the CPU is at 100%, isn't it expectable that you get big delays?

Comment: the problem in this case is, that is an old customer-version. i cant test it at this system! but they tell me, this is happened in this new year at the first working day. in last year it wasn´t

Comment: @Tom what code parts you missing?

Comment: Since I don't know how your *real* code looks like, I can't tell what's missing, but since your first version of your code snippet was flawed I wonder *if* there is more missing stuff. But infos your question currently misses are: How do you start threads? How do you stop them? Do you use a thread pool and how large is it? How many threads are running (usually) and were running then the CPU was at 100%?

Comment: there are only two possibilities in the **given code** for such delay: `LOG.info` and `Thread.sleep`. That is, or logging is blocking or the CPU is being used by other threads/processes...

Comment: @Tom i give you more code

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger is it possible, that the logging ist blocking?

Comment: @duke_42 why not? there can be anything inside the method, e.g., sending log entries through network, waiting a file to unlock, ... **I** have no idea of what that line is doing, only what it apparently is supposed to do (by its name).

Comment: is there no more code inside the waiting loop? Why not just wait for 10 seconds? I would also advice to put some logging inside the `catch (InterruptedException e)`

Comment: I can only second [Gustave’s comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545810/#comment70296566_41545810). If your CPU is at 100%, everything will slow down, so why not this thread too? The fact that it does some sleeps in-between doesn’t remove the slowdown affecting the rest of the code. You should focus on the reason for the 100% CPU load, instead of wasting your time with that thread. `sleep` isn’t causing the CPU load.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the tip to wast not time with this `sleep`. Maybe i can do a thread dump to see what ever...